# how to fetch a data based on id conditions were same

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

here is my below xml under that table due based on CTD_CTD_PKG_ID(some time under table CTD_CTD_PKG_ID id was same means we need take data from both tables ) this pack id we need to generate a text file with the help of xsl style sheet but how to write logic code in xslt

for some fields data were same for that type of records for me dont want to repeat once again only once i need but how to control if i am getting two records of CTD_LANG_ID needed to display once but i have written xslt i was thinking it was not correct we will fail when we are have xml with one more table with different package id(CTD_CTD_PKG_ID) at that time lang id may be different than E but this xslt were showing E it self ...

```
 <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
 <NewDataSet>
  <Table>
<RECORD_TYPE_CODE>CTD</RECORD_TYPE_CODE>
<MSG_TYPE_CODE>O102</MSG_TYPE_CODE>
<CTD_SEQ_NUM>089938</CTD_SEQ_NUM>    
<CTD_CTD_PKG_ID>345</CTD_CTD_PKG_ID>
<CTD_LANG_ID>E</CTD_LANG_ID>
 </Table>
 <Table>
<RECORD_TYPE_CODE>ITD</RECORD_TYPE_CODE>
<MSG_TYPE_CODE>O103</MSG_TYPE_CODE>
<CTD_SEQ_NUM>089939</CTD_SEQ_NUM>    
<CTD_CTD_PKG_ID>345</CTD_CTD_PKG_ID>
<CTD_LANG_ID>E</CTD_LANG_ID>
</Table>   
</NewDataSet>
```

I HAVE A WRITTEN MY OWN XSLT LOGIC BUT IT DOESN'T WORK

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<xsl:output method="text" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:param name="PackageId"  />


<xsl:template match="/">        
    <xsl:apply-templates select="NewDataSet/Table[CTD_CTD_PKG_ID ='345']"/>     
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="NewDataSet/Table[CTD_CTD_PKG_ID ='345']">

    <xsl:value-of select= "concat(':25:',./TRAN_TYPE_CODE)"/>,<xsl:text/>
    <xsl:if test ="./RECORD_TYPE_CODE"  >
        <xsl:if test=" position() &gt; 1"></xsl:if>
        <xsl:text/><xsl:value-of select= "concat(':20:',./RECORD_TYPE_CODE)"/>,<xsl:text/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test ="./MSG_TYPE_CODE" >
        <xsl:if test=" position() &gt; 1"></xsl:if>
        <xsl:text/><xsl:value-of select= "concat(':21:',./MSG_TYPE_CODE)"/>,<xsl:text/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test ="./CTD_SEQ_NUM" >
        <xsl:if test=" position() &gt; 1"></xsl:if>
        <xsl:text/><xsl:value-of select= "concat(':22:',./CTD_SEQ_NUM)"/>,<xsl:text/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Execpected output

**:25:E,:20:CTD,:21:O102N,:22:089938,:20:ITD,:21:O103N,:22:089939,**

Comment: for some fields data were same for that type of records for me dont want to repeat once again only once i need but how to control if i am getting two records of CTD_LANG_ID needed to display once but i have written xslt i was thinking it was not correct we will fail when we are have xml with one more table with different package id(CTD_CTD_PKG_ID) at that time lang id may be different than E but this xslt were showing E it self ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:param name="packageId" select="345"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="NewDataSet/Table[CTD_CTD_PKG_ID = $packageId]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Table">
    <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">,</xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="RECORD_TYPE_CODE | MSG_TYPE_CODE | CTD_SEQ_NUM"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Table/*">
    <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">,</xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: i need to add a prefix for each and every type code is that possible with your sample for example  :20:CTD,:21:0102,:22:089938, :20:ITD,:21:0103,:22:089939

Comment: Replace the single `template match="Table/*"` with three templates, one for each type of element node e.g. for the record type `<xsl:template match="Table/RECORD_TYPE_CODE"><xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">,</xsl:if><xsl:value-of select="concat(':20:', .)"/></xsl:template>`, then the same for the other two element types, only change the concat expression in each template to output the prefix you want.

Comment: honnen i m using above for prefix concatination it was gud right now we did if any tags were repeated means we fetched up similarly for example CTD_LANG_ID is having same value in both table then i need only one time in output data , so that i have tried by quiting that position line even though all records were coming in data how to control expected output as :E,CTD,0102,089938,ITD,0103,089939

Answer (score 0):

To stay with your code...

You are performing `xsl:if` tests starting from the wrong context. The template context is `Table`. Also the `xsl:text` is used in the wrong way. For instance, you should change test with:

```
<xsl:if test="RECORD_TYPE_CODE">
    <xsl:value-of select= "RECORD_TYPE_CODE"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
```

This if you want omit empty values in your output like `,,`. Moreover you will need to change the final condition to avoid the last comma:

```
<xsl:if test="CTD_SEQ_NUM">
        <xsl:value-of select= "CTD_SEQ_NUM"/>
            <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::Table)>0">
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
</xsl:if>
```